# How to fetch the DNS server that my machine is using?

Tags: dns, dig

How can I programatically fetch the DNS server that my machine is using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`what-is-my-dns` command](https://github.com/bevry/dorothy/blob/master/commands/what-is-my-dns) from the [`Dorothy dotfile ecosystem`](https://github.com/bevry/dorothy).

You can run it standalone by doing:

```
sh -ic "$(curl -fsSL https://dorothy.bevry.workers.dev/commands/what-is-my-dns)"
```

Or manually by installing [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) first then running:

```bsh
dig cloudflare.com | rg -o 'SERVER: .+?[(]([^)]+)' --replace '$1'
```

Comment: This is _unnecessarily_ complex for what amounts to looking at the 1st "nameserver" line in /etc/resolv.conf...